# Can't use CMD+V Shortcut to copy paste into certain apps, but right click menu works fine

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave

In iMessage, the Mail app and Slack, if I copy an image to clipboard, then use Cmd+V to paste it into an active iMessage conversation, nothing happens. However, in apps like Discord or Firefox, this works fine.

However, if I click Edit -> Paste or right click the message box and click paste, it appears. It's really frustrating to have Cmd+V not work. Does anyone know why? It's always been this way, since I bought this Macbook earlier this year, refurbished.

MBP 13 inch using MacOS Mojave

Comment: is it only in iMessage that the command +v does not work, but it works in other apps ? is it for the image only? but it works for text !

Comment: To the right of the Edit -> Paste menu item, is the keyboard shortcut (⌘V) shown?

Comment: @user3052786 yes, the edit shortcut is shown.  Clicking that edit paste button works, but not the shortcut!

Comment: @Buscar웃Yes, it works in other apps!

Comment: That is... bizarre. You mentioned it was refurbished, was there a clean OS installed when you got the machine? Is it possible you might have installed tools that might interfere, keymap editors, remote management, etc.? Do you use shared pasteboards with any other Apple devices you have? Just spitballing here, can't imagine why this wouldn't be working.

Comment: Just as a starting point for troubleshooting/sanity check, the [Additional Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=Additional%20Tools%20for%20Xcode) includes Clipboard Viewer.app if you want to try that out. You might need to sign up for the free dev program.

Comment: @user3052786 Yes, it was refurbishes and sold by Apple. I have three tools installed that access the clipboard, all of which I've eliminated. They are iTerm2, Virtualbox and Lightshot (screenshot app). I've turned them all off before opening iMessage, there is no change.

I tried downloading the Clipboard Viewer app, thanks, however it does confirm that the right content is in my clipboard.

Comment: Interestingly, I've discovered this is actually a problem with several other of my apps Some examples include Slack, the built-in Mail app, and as mentioned before, iMessage. I use these infrequently enough that I never thought about it. They all exhibit the same behavior. Cmd+V does nothing, I need to right click or use the edit Menu. Discord and Firefox (on sites like Imgur) work fine...but I don't know why. At least I know it isn't iMessage though, which is an improvement. I'm currently running through all running processes trying to find a trace...

Comment: Oo, slightly more information. I looked at the 'Edit' menu for Slack, and CMD+V is mapped to 'Paste and Match Style', but CMD+Shift+V' is mapped to 'Paste'. In both Slack and Mail, Cmd+Shift+V pastes the image directly. Still no dice on Messages. Messages makes a 'boop' sound when I try to paste into it.

Answer (score 4):

With help from @user3052786 , I've found the issue.

The reason why many (but not all) apps were failing to paste with the shortcut (but Edit menu -> Paste or Right click -> Paste worked fine) is because I previously followed the following tutorial on how to make my clipboard content attempt to match the output document's text style on paste.

https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/set-paste-match-style-default-mac-osx/

I did this because I was using OneNote for Mac and pasting a lot of content between different documents for note-taking.

**The fix:** Simply remove the 'CMD+V -> Paste and Match Style' mapping from Keyboard shortcuts in MacOS Settings, as shown in reverse by the tutorial.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Usually the menubar item reflects any keyboard shortcuts you assign (or reassign) so ⌘V shouldn't have been there at all. Glad you solved your problem anyhow :)

Comment: thanks for posting the answer here! that "bug" annoyed me for some time now!

Comment: Solved it for me! Steps: Apple Menu > System Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts. Then expand the "All Applications" menu, look for "Paste and Match Style," and delete that entry.